# If $\cos\pi\theta$ is algebraic and $\theta$ is irrational, what is the set of possible $\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry, rational-numbers

I know that $a= \cos \pi \theta$  is an algebraic number ($\theta$ is rational). I want to prove that if $\cos\pi\theta$ is rational, then the possible only possible values of $\theta$ are $0,±1/2,±1$
Thanks for your help.

Comment: $\cos (\frac {\pi}3)=\frac 12$

Comment: Actually, the header question says $\theta$ is irrational, but the question says it is rational.  I assume the latter is intended, but clarification is called for.

Comment: In addition, I think it is meant that $ \cos(\pi \theta) $ is one of $ 0, \pm 1/2, \pm 1 $, since the assertion is false otherwise.

Comment: @Starfall  Ah, you are probably right about that.  In that case of course we have [Niven's Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Niven's_Theorem).

Comment: Yes - although proofwiki's proof is quite long, I provide a much shorter proof in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the question is about Niven's theorem (it is rather poorly phrased) so I give a short proof.

If $ \cos(\pi \theta) = \cos( \pi p / q) $, then we have that $ 2\cos(\pi \theta) = \zeta_{2q}^p + \zeta_{2q}^{-p} $ where $ \zeta_{2q} = e^{\pi i/q} $ is a primitive root of $ X^{2q} - 1 = 0 $, and therefore is an algebraic integer. This implies that $ 2\cos(\pi \theta) $ is an algebraic integer for rational $ \theta $. The only rational algebraic integers are the rational integers, so if $ 2 \cos(\pi \theta) $ is rational it must be an integer. As it is between $ -2 $ and $ 2 $, the result follows immediately.